# how to detect an element that is clicked from many the same element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, onclick

I have a lot of elements that have the same tags as follow:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>1</a>
    ...
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>2</a>
    ...
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>3</a>
    ...
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

User can click on any  element. How can I detect the element that user click? (I don't know the number of  element before. I can be five or there or any number).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the clicked element using `this`. For example:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text()); //displays the clicked element's text.
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$(this)` or `this` to refer to source of event.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
  alert(this.innerText);
});
```

It is better to use a `class` to be specific, so that the event is bind with intended elements instead of any a on the page. You can assign a class to elements on which you want to bind click event and use [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind the event.

```
<a class="myclass">1</a>

$('.myclass').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
    alert(this.innerText);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding on anchor tag

```
$('ul li a').on('click',function(){

    alert($(this).text()); //This will give the text
    alert(this.id); //This will give you the id if you have id for anch tag.

});
```

Binding on `li`

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){

    alert($(this).text()); //This will give the text of anchor ta in your case
    alert($(this).index()); //This will give you the index of li with respect to its siblings.

    });
```